# Leiningen and local repo dependencies issue

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm using Leiningen and local repo, and here's my project.clj. Camelclojure is local jar.

```
(defproject mashup-dsl "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]

            [enlive "1.1.1"]
            [ring/ring-core "1.1.8"]
            [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.8"]
            [net.cgrand/moustache "1.0.0"]
            [ring/ring-devel "1.1.8"]
            [compojure "1.1.5"]
            [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]
            [org.apache.camel/camel-core "2.11.0"]
            [org.apache.camel/camel-component "1.4.0"]     
            [org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.7"]
            [camelclojure "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"]

          ]
 :repositories {"local"  "C:/Users/pvmd/.m2/repository"}
 :plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.5.2"]])
```

I've added a local jar to Maven's repository, but when I run

```
lein deps
```

Here's what I get as an error

```
C:\Users\pvmd\git\mashup-dsl\mashup-dsl>lein deps
Could not transfer artifact camelclojure:camelclojure:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from/to
local (C:/Users/pvmd/.m2/repository): No connector available to access reposito
ry local (C:/Users/pvmd/.m2/repository) of type default using the available factories      FileRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

I don't use proxy, so its definately a dependency issue, I just can't find the reason why...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get ***camelclojure***? I didn't find it in MVNRepositories, neither in Clojars. Maybe the project is renamed to something else?

Any way, you should include the ***groupId*** also:

```
[info.kovanovic/camelclojure "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"]
```

But still, I would suggest to check the current status of the project. It looks to me that it is renamed.

Comment: camelclojure is local jar that comes from a project created by coleague of mine

Comment: It works now, thank you, but now I can't seem to load a namespace from it: user=> (require 'info.kovanovic.camelclojure.dsl)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate info/kovanovic/camelclojure/dsl__init.class or info/kovanovic/camelclojure/dsl.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

Comment: Maybe your colleague renamed/moved dsl.clj to something else.

Comment: no, it's not that, jar is local, and I've already installed it using mvn install command, it's in my local repository...it's probably the problem with names....I'll try something else